# Host registration failed in Ambari

Tags: ambari

I am trying to install ambari agents using ambari server. I have done all the necessary pre-requisites for ambari like iptables, selinux disabled, NP tables enabled, passwordless ssh. 
Still the issue is not resolved. Below is the snapshot of the error. Can anyone suggest me with the plausible solution for this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please update your question with the log. I am also unable to see any errors in your screenshot. Both commands exited with code 0

Comment: This is the only log i am getting. THat's why i am not able to figure out the problem. Please suggest me what can be the issue